# Equality in distribution - study of a condition

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

Given a class $\mathcal{P}$ on a Borel measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{F})$. Let  $q\in\mathcal{P}$ and  $p\in\mathcal{P}$ denote two arbitrary density functions and suppose that the following equation holds for any $F\in\mathfrak{F}$

$$\int_{F}q(x)\cdot p(x)dx= \int_{F}q(x)\cdot q(x)dx \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall F\in\mathfrak{F}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1)$$

My question is: *does the equation 1 imply that $p(x)=q(x)$ a.s. for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$?*

**Attempted proof:**

if equation 1) holds therefore it is also true that

$$q(x)\cdot p(x)= q(x)\cdot q(x) \ \ \ \ \ a.s.$$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R} $

which implies that
$$p(x)= q(x) \ \ \ \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \ \ \ \ a.s.$$

Comment: Looks a lot like the Fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variations. You definitely can't get equality everywhere, but you could probably get "almost surely" or "almost everywhere", depending on the context. If you impose smoothness conditions on the functions, you might be able to do better.

Comment: The answer clearly is no, because at a minimum the statement needs to be qualified with "almost surely with respect to $q.$"

Comment: @whuber I edited as you suggested

Comment: @Adrian Keister thank you, I thought to fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variation me too. Any suggestion on how to use it in this case?

Comment: Well, $q$ has to be arbitrary in the Lemma, and then you could use the function $f=q-p.$ $q$ would also have to be compactly supported and smooth - not sure you have that in this case.

Comment: @Adrian Keister unfortuntely I need to generalize